# How to fill missing values grouped on id and based on time period from index date

Tags: r, date, fill

I want to fill in missing values for a data.frame based on a period of time within groups of ID.

For the latest registration_dat within the same ID group, I want to fill in with previous values in the ID group but only if the registration_dat is within 1 year of the latest registration_dat in the ID group.

Sample version of my data:

```
ID registration_dat  value1      value2
1  2020-03-04          NA          NA
1  2019-05-06          33          25
1  2019-01-02          32          21
3  2021-10-31          NA          NA
3  2018-10-12          33          NA
3  2018-10-10          25          35
4  2020-01-02          NA          NA
4  2019-10-31          32          83
4  2019-09-20          33          56
8  2019-12-12          NA          NA
8  2019-10-31          NA          43
8  2019-08-12          32          46
```

Desired output:

```
ID registration_dat  value1      value2
1  2020-03-04          33          25
1  2019-05-06          33          25
1  2019-01-02          32          21
3  2021-10-31          NA          NA
3  2018-10-12          33          NA
3  2018-10-10          25          35
4  2020-01-02          32          83
4  2019-10-31          32          83
4  2019-09-20          33          56
8  2019-12-12          32          43
8  2019-10-31          NA          43
8  2019-08-12          32          46
```

I am later filtering the data so that i get one unique ID based on the latest registration date and I want this row to have as little missing data as possible hence I want to do this for all columns in the dataframe. However I do not want NA values being filled in by values in previous dates if its more than 1 year apart from the latest registration date. My dataframe has 14 columns and 3 million+ rows so I would need it to work on a much bigger data.frame than the one shown as an example.

I'd appreciate any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a small function (`f`, below) to handle each value column.

1. Make a grouped ID, and generate a `rowid` (this is only to retain your original order)

```
dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>% 
  arrange(registration_dat) %>% 
  group_by(ID)
```

2. Make a function that takes a `df` and `val` column, and returns and updated `df` with `val` fixed

```
f <- function(df, val) {
  bind_rows(
    df %>% filter(is.na({{val}}) & row_number()!=n()),
    df %>% filter(!is.na({{val}}) | row_number()==n()) %>% 
      mutate({{val}} := if_else(is.na({{val}}) & registration_dat-lag(registration_dat)<365, lag({{val}}),{{val}}))
  )
}
```

3. Apply the function to the columns of interest

```
dat = f(dat,value1)
dat = f(dat,value2)
```

4. If you want, recover the original order

```
dat %>% arrange(rowid) %>% select(-rowid)
```

Output:

```
      ID registration_dat value1 value2
   <int> <date>            <int>  <int>
 1     1 2020-03-04           33     25
 2     1 2019-05-06           33     25
 3     1 2019-01-02           32     21
 4     3 2021-10-31           NA     NA
 5     3 2018-10-12           33     NA
 6     3 2018-10-10           25     35
 7     4 2020-01-02           32     83
 8     4 2019-10-31           32     83
 9     4 2019-09-20           33     56
10     8 2019-12-12           32     46
11     8 2019-10-31           NA     43
12     8 2019-08-12           32     46
```

#### Update:

The OP wants the final row (i.e the last registration_dat) per ID. With 3 million rows and 14 value columns, I would use `data.table` and do something like this:

```
library(data.table)

f <- function(df) {
  df = df[df[1,registration_dat]-registration_dat<=365]
  df[1,value:=df[2:.N][!is.na(value)][1,value]][1]
}

dcast(
  melt(setDT(dat), id=c("ID", "registration_dat"))[order(-registration_dat),f(.SD), by=.(ID,variable)],
  ID+registration_dat~variable, value.var="value"
)
```

Output:

```
      ID registration_dat value1 value2
   <int>           <Date>  <int>  <int>
1:     1       2020-03-04     33     25
2:     3       2021-10-31     NA     NA
3:     4       2020-01-02     32     83
4:     8       2019-12-12     32     43
```

Comment: Nice solution! But I think it might be better to use `across()` to manipulate multiple columns with a single function. If there are 100 columns in this case, you need to run `dat = f(dat,value*)` 100 times or pass it into a loop, which is far from the  aesthetics of `dplyr`.

Comment: That's a good point @DarrenTsai. Thanks.. If I was actually working with this dataset, I'd be using data.table anyway, and I would just go straight to what the OP wants, which is filtering on the final row (the latest registration date). See updated alternative that does that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `across()` to manipulate multiple columns at the same time. Note that I use `date1 - years(1) <= date2` rather than `date1 - 365 <= date2` to identify if a date is within 1 year of the latest one, which can take a leap year (366 days) into account.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(desc(registration_dat), .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("value"),
    ~ if_else(row_number() == 1 & is.na(.x) & registration_dat - years(1) <= registration_dat[which.max(!is.na(.x))],
              .x[which.max(!is.na(.x))], .x))) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 12 x 4
#       ID registration_dat value1 value2
#    <int> <date>            <int>  <int>
#  1     1 2020-03-04           33     25
#  2     1 2019-05-06           33     25
#  3     1 2019-01-02           32     21
#  4     3 2021-10-31           NA     NA
#  5     3 2018-10-12           33     NA
#  6     3 2018-10-10           25     35
#  7     4 2020-01-02           32     83
#  8     4 2019-10-31           32     83
#  9     4 2019-09-20           33     56
# 10     8 2019-12-12           32     43
# 11     8 2019-10-31           NA     43
# 12     8 2019-08-12           32     46
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L,
8L, 8L), registration_dat = structure(c(18325, 18022, 17898,
18931, 17816, 17814, 18263, 18200, 18159, 18242, 18200, 18120
), class = "Date"), value1 = c(NA, 33L, 32L, NA, 33L, 25L, NA,
32L, 33L, NA, NA, 32L), value2 = c(NA, 25L, 21L, NA, NA, 35L,
NA, 83L, 56L, NA, 43L, 46L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-12L))
```